# HTTP Error 400 in Android

Tags: android, json, http, https, httpresponse

I am trying to execute the below command:

```
curl -d @request.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=your_API_key_here
```

For this the code I have written follows here.

```
public class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Search_Button.setClickable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(DisplaySummaryActivity.this,
                "Please wait..while we bring you the flight details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Search_Button.setClickable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            HttpsURLConnection connection = null;

            URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=MyKey");
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(7200000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(720000);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.connect();

            JSONObject request_hdr = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray slice = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

            request.put("solutions", 1);
            request.put("refundable", "false");

            JSONObject addl_info = new JSONObject();
            addl_info.put("adultCount", Num_Adult);
            addl_info.put("infantInLapCount", Num_Infant);
            addl_info.put("infantInSeatCount", 0);
            addl_info.put("childCount", 0);
            addl_info.put("seniorCount", 0);
            request.put("passengers", addl_info);

            data.put("origin", Origin);
            data.put("destination", Destination);
            data.put("date", Start_Date);
            slice.put(data);
            request.put("slice", slice);

            request_hdr.put("request", request);

            OutputStreamWriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.write(String.valueOf(request_hdr.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
            output.flush();
            output.close();

            int HttpResult = connection.getResponseCode();

            if(HttpResult == 400){
                Toast.makeText(DisplaySummaryActivity.this,
                        "Something went wrong here!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(HttpResult == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                StringBuilder jsonresponse = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
                String receiveString = null;

                while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    jsonresponse.append(receiveString);
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
            }

            connection.disconnect();
        }catch(JSONException JE){
            JE.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem here is, I am always getting a HTTP response code as 400. I searched here and found out the below lines of code.

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
String algorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

I have added this in my code and tried, but with this I am not able to connect at all.

Now my question is: AM I DOING ANYTHING WRONG HERE? HOW TO GET RID OF ERROR CODE 400?
Any suggestions and/or sample code would be really appreciated.

Comment: Well what does response code 400 mean?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue myself by changing the input parameters. :)
Thanks!